# Запрос на ссылку из массива Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, запрос

Есть такой код:

```
href = []
for link in soup.findAll("a",{'class':'styles-link-36uWZ'}):
    a = link.get("href")
    href.append(a)

q = len(href)
c = 0
while c < q:
    try:
        page_avito1 = requests.get(href[c])
        soup1 = BeautifulSoup(page_avito1)
        c+=1
        for rows in soup1.findAll("li",{'class':'item-params-list-item'}):
            print(rows.text)
    except:
        pass
```

Суть в том, что одним запросом я нахожу ссылки и добавляю их в массив `href`. Потом отправляю запрос на каждую из этих ссылок в массиве

Выдает ошибку:

> page_avito1 = requests.get(href[c]) line 69, in get return
> request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs) line 50, in request
> response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs) line 451,
> in request prep = self.prepare_request(req) line 382, in
> prepare_request hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks), line
> 304, in prepare self.prepare_url(url, params) line 362, in prepare_url
> to_native_string(url, 'utf8'))) requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
> Invalid URL

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: page_avito1 = requests.get(href[c])
 line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
line 451, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
line 382, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
 line 304, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
 line 362, in prepare_url
    to_native_string(url, 'utf8')))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL

Comment: А url какой, раз код на схему ругается?

Comment: типа таких: /moskva/kvartiry/2-k_kvartira_69.1_m_46_et._1090821057

Comment: нет, это не Schema. url должен быть типа http://www.url.ru/page  - то есть полный URI с указанием протокола

Comment: href.append("https://www.avito.ru"+(link.get("href"))) # строка добавляет в массив https://www.avito.ru + /moskva/kvartiry/2-k_kvartira_69.1_m_46_et._1090821057. Т.е на выходе полный URL. И получается вот такая ошибка: lif len(markup) <= 256 and (
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Comment: забыл, что здесь в ссылках съедаются протоколы. попробуйте вместо "avito.ru"  - 
 `"http://avito.ru"`

Comment: Не помогло, такие же ошибки